# InDesign: Blank pages on 1,4 when creating a booklet?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I'm trying to supply the printer with a 2-page saddle up print job - which I'm assuming is a 2 page spread stapled in the middle and folded.

The document is a 22 page booklet, The 1st page is the cover and the 22nd page is the back of the booklet.

My problem is there is blank pages on page 1 and 4 - I do not understand why this is happening?

Comment: KMSTR is correct, but as an aside: is the printer asking you to impose the booklet before submission? I usually let their pre-press people do this.

Comment: Have the same experience with printers. Document supplied in order of page numbers. They won't accept 22 pages though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a Booklet must have a page-count that can be divided by 4. Why? **Each sheet has 4 sides**, even if you leave them blank, they will be physically there. You will have to go for 20 pages or 24. 22 leaves 2 empty. Which is what you are seeing in the final booklet.

Comment: Quickest fix: insert blank pages for page 2 and 23 (the inside of the cover)

Answer (score 0):

KMSTR has the answer here. Just to add that the quality and timing of communication you get from the printers on this kind of issue is dependent on the relationship you have with them, and to some degree the price you pay.

I am guessing this is towards the lower end of the market, which may well be appropriate for this job. But you've not got what you expected, with no explanation, and likely to cause significant delay in delivery to end client.

Higher up the scale you'd expect an email or call when prepress try to impose the document.

A the top of the scale you might have an automated or human checking of your artwork for issues as soon as it is uploaded to the printer, allowing you to correct the issue immediately.